# Autofac - how to register 2 different version of the same type with the same name

Tags: c#, reflection, types, autofac, multiple-versions

Looking for some help on this. Would be much appreciated.

What I'm trying to accomplish is registering multiple versions of a type to maintain backwards compatibility on an API. This API will allow operations to be executed using older versions of the code.

My code does the following to accomplish this:

1. Load each version of each DLL's types into memory.

   ```
   foreach (var directory in Directories)
   {
       assembliesToLoad.AddRange(directory.EnumerateFiles("*.dll").Select(file => Assembly.LoadFile(file.FullName)));
   }
   foreach (var assembly in assembliesToLoad)
   {
       RegisterActivityTypesFromAssembly(assembly);
   }
   ```
2. Register them using Autofac in a loop.

   ```
   var type = value.Key;
   var version = $"{value.Value.Major}.{value.Value.Minor}.{value.Value.Build}";
   var typeId = $"{keyValuePair.Key}@{version}";
   if (type != null)
   {
       foreach (var interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
       {
           Builder.RegisterType(type).Named(typeId, interfaceType);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Then I load it later in the pipeline based on the version specified in the API.

   ```
   var autofacTypeId = $"{_typeId}@{_version}";
   _activity = Scope.ResolveNamed<IActivity>(autofacTypeId);
   ```

I've noticed this code will resolve the current version of the type no problem. Attempting to resolve older versions it fails on. What am I doing wrong here? It seems like the older version types go away for some reason, even though during the loading phase they seem to be loaded just fine after reflection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] that we could run in a console app at our end. I am particularly interested in seeing the source code for the two classes with the same name.

Comment: Normally you won't be able to load different versions of the same assembly into the AppDomain/context without "unpredictable" outcomes. 
Do you need to execute from both versions in the same runtime instance? Or just stick to one?
If the former you probably need to rework the part which uses the older version of the assembly to run in it's own AppDomain, if the latter limit the loaded assembly to the desired version (note: just reflecting an assembly loads it).

Comment: It seems like AppDomain is the preferred way to do this. Do you have any useful links on how to utilize multiple AppDomains well?